# Problem related to an analytic function

Tags: complex-analysis

I came across the following problem :

> Let $g \colon \Bbb C \to \Bbb C$ be analytic.Suppose that $|g(\frac{1}{n})| \le \frac{1}{n^{3/2}}$ for each $n \in N.$ Then prove that $\{n^2g(\frac{1}{n})\}$ is bounded.

$|g(\frac{1}{n})| \le \frac{1}{n^{3/2}} \implies |n^2g(\frac{1}{n})| \le \sqrt n$....Now,I am not sure which way to go.

Comment: show derivative is zero at origin and the power series starts at second power

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $g$ is continuous, $g(0)=0$. Show that $g'(0)$ also vanishes.

If that is the case, then there is an entire function $h$ such $g(z)=z^2h(z)$, and then $n^2g(\tfrac1n)=n^2\tfrac{1}{n^2}h(\tfrac1n)=h(\tfrac1n)$ so that the set $\{n^2g(\tfrac1n):n\in\mathbb N\}$ is obviously bounded, because $h$ is bounded on the unit disc.

Comment: Compute $g'(0)$ using its definition as a limit of a quotient!

Comment: There is no need to provide links: you can do all these proofs yourself.

Comment: In order to show that $h$ exists, notice that it *must* be $g(z)/z^2$ when $z\neq0$, so you only need to show that thefunctin $g(z)/z^2$ can be extended to the whole of $\mathbb C$.